# Vue element class transition

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, transition

I am trying to do a transition between two different css classes where the only difference is the background image.

The Vue code:

```
<div id="flip-list-demo" class="demo">
    <transition-group name="flip-list" tag="ol">
      <div v-for="item, in items" class="licontainer" v-bind:key="item.text">
        <li :data-shares="item.shares" :data-pos="item.datapos">
          <a href="#">
        {{ item.text }}
        </a>
        </li>
        <transition name="fade">
          <div :id = "'icon' + item.uid" :class="item.icon"></div>
        </transition>
      </div>
    </transition-group>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
ol .red, .yellow, .green {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}

ol .yellow {
    transition: background-image 2s;
  background-image: Long SVG code;
}

ol .green {
  transition: background-image 2s;
background-image: Long SVG code;
}

ol .red{
  transition: background-image 2s;
    background-image: Long SVG code;
}
```

The icon property is updated dynamically inside the Vue instance in a method which triggers a redraw and changes the icons.

My question is if it is possible to use transitions, specifically opacity fade between the two classes? I am not adding or removing an item just updating the class so i am having trouble using the Vue transition classes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not bind classes to a specific condition (see Vue documentation https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) and then use the `transition`-property in CSS (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding `transition: background-image 2s;` at the top of every css class before the background-image.

Answer (score 0):

when you change class in your dom and need transition , must do like this

```html
<div :class="{active: true}" ></div>
```

```css
div {
 background-color:red;
 transition:all 2s ease;
}

.active {

background-color: red;

}
```